# NSScollView with flipped documentView is causing strange animation issues

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation, nsview, nsscrollview

I'm experience the strangest thing. I'm working on a project that I started noticing this issue, so I created a sandboxed test to simplify the problem and see if I can figure it out.

I have document based application with a single window controller. inside that are these objects:

- Subclassed NSScrollView with isFlipped=YES
- Subclassed NSView with isFlipped=YES, this is the documentView in the above scrollview.
- An NSImage in the document view

Then I try and fade the image to alpha 0 like this:

```
- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(test) userInfo:nil repeats:FALSE];
}

- (void) test {
    [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
    [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:4];
    self.errorOutline.animator.alphaValue = 0;
    [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
}
```

This is how it looks in Xcode:

[image: Xcode Layout]

This is what happens when it starts animating:

[image: While animating it breaks up]

I've noticed that if I resize the window continually while it's animating, I get a ghosting image like effect where I an see the rest of the image.

Another strange issue is that if I set isFlipped=NO, then the issue doesn't happen. Which is not an option - the whole reason I'm flipping the view is so it's easier to manage adding cells to it without calculating positions and heights backwards.

**Update:** I've filed a radar bug as this is a really strange issue. http://openradar.appspot.com/20680289

Comment: Why are you flipping both the scroll view and the document (scrolled) view? You should only need to flip the document view.

Comment: Thanks yeah I switched that, but it doesn't matter. It's still bugging.